# How to exclude managed packages in Force IDE?

Tags: apex, managed-package, ide, force.com-ide, refresh

Whenever I right click on my project in Force IDE and select refresh from server then it takes considerable amount of time. I guess the reason is it is trying to refresh even the managed package apps, classes and pages from server but I am interested in refreshing only unmanaged classes, pages,  components and etc.

Below is the package.xml file for my project in force IDE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <version>33.0</version>
</Package>
```

Below is the screenshot showing managed packages in Force IDE:

[image]

I also went into Add/Remove metadata components section to remove managed package components but nothing is selected to uncheck:

[image]

If nothing is present in package.xml and add/remove metadata components then why is it downloading managed packages to Force IDE??

Answer (score 1):

You can update resources individually in Eclipse by right clicking them, or select an entire folder such as Classes, or Pages to update only those resources. I usually refresh my entire src folder which includes everything but the referenced packages. Also your classes, pages and components that you want to sync need to be selected in the Add/Remove Metadata settings.

Comment: Looks like it is a bug in Force IDE..I posted the same on Force IDE. Here is the link : https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore/issues/147

Answer (score 1):

Like Ross mentioned, you can refresh particular folders to reduce refresh time.  I was also looking to exclude managed packages because  I am currently performing an audit and globally searching all metadata and do not want to see results from managed packages. I did end up finding a solution which was to delete all local managed package folders on my hard drive and sync the Eclipse project. This approach doesn't affect the managed package metadata stored in the org (which is read-only in Eclipse anyway), but removes it from my search results so perfect workaround.

Comment: Once you delete managed package folders from your local system and then select refresh from server, does it retrieve the managed package folders again? Thanks!

Comment: If you select Refresh from Server when you right-click on the project, yes it will re-download everything including the managed packages folders.  But if you follow Ross' suggestion and only right-click the folders you want refreshed (like the classes, triggers, pages folders or the parent src if your src folder does not include include managed packages like mine did), it will not refresh managed package folders.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I knew that already but my question is why is it downloading the components which are not mentioned in the package.xml? I posted the same on the Force IDE and they accepted it as a bug..Here is the link for your reference https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore/issues/147. I knew that I can just refresh the folders that I want.